# renaming a url is not working with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

i am using the following rewrite rule to rename the url :-

`RewriteRule ^home$ index.php`

but this is not working. So i used the other rule i.e

`RewriteRule ^home.html$ index.php`

Its is showing `404 error` .

Note: the same code is working in other site , but not in mine.
Thanx !!

Comment: Is mod_rewrite enabled? Is that your full htaccess?

Comment: No, I don't know abt it, plz tell me where u chk it, its online and I don't know where to chk in the cpanel, the server is apache

Comment: @SumeetMathew If you are expecting any help, I would recommend talking in regular English and not in some txtspeak. Also: Please GOOGLE how to find out if mod_rewrite is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to turn `mod_rewrite` on before your rules:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^home(\.html?)?$ index.php [NC,L]
```

This would rewrite `/home`, `/home.htm` and `/home.html` to `index.php`. If this doesn't work check that `mod_rewrite` is enabled in your `httpd.conf` file: *(remove # before)*

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

Change `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride All` everywhere. Restart Apache.